# How do I return a dictionary from a grouping operation with the grouping factor as the key?

Tags: c#, linq

The code below creates a list of strings.  The grouping factor is the StoreID (Item1).  What I want is a dictionary with the grouping factor (i.e. StoreID) as the key and the string as the value.  The input file is just a text file that contains 3 columns: StoreID, Quantity, and something else (which I can't remember) but these values are just concatenated together for each line for a store to make a comma and bar separated string.

```
var query = skuStoreStockLevel.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
                .Select(g => g.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                                         (sb, x) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1},{2},{3}", "|", x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3),
                                         (sb) => sb.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) to do this:

```
var query = skuStoreStockLevel.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
            .ToDictionary(
                 g => g.Key,
                 g => g.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                                     (sb, x) => sb.AppendFormat("|{0},{1},{2}", x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3),
                                     (sb) => sb.ToString()));
```